# Разве внешний класс не имеет доступа к членам вложенного класса

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Шилдт в своей книге пишет, что "... вложенный класс имеет доступ к членам своего внешнего класса. НО (Внимание!) ***внешний класс не имеет доступа к членам внутреннего класса***". И тут вопрос,- что именно имелось ввиду? как не имеет доступа, когда в примере, приведенном ниже, метод внешнего класса получает доступ к члену своего внутреннего класса без проблем.

```
class VneshnClass {

    void test (){
        VnutrClass vnutObj = new VnutrClass ();
        vnutObj.vnutr_x++; // этим методом внешнего класса меняем значение 
                           // поля внутреннего класса
        vnutObj.displayVn();
    }

    class VnutrClass {  // внутренний класс
        int vnutr_x = 33;  // вот наше поле внутреннего класса

        void displayVn(){  // метод вложенного класса
            System.out.println("vnutr_x = "+vnutr_x);
        }
    }
}

class MainClass {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        VneshnClass obj = new VneshnClass();
        obj.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё зависит от метода доступа: private, public, protected.

Comment: @maestro забыли ещё один метод доступа - как в примере автора вопроса, без всяких словечек. Упоминается как "no modifier"

Comment: Возможно это трудности перевода, а на самом деле Шилдт совсем другое написал? Или он тоже не разбирается в предмете. Внешний класс имеет доступ к членам внутреннего класса на общих основаниях, а не аналогичных тем, на которых внутренний класс имеет внешний.

Comment: Нет, модификаторы доступа здесь не причём. Речь идет в принципе о возможности доступа внешнего к внутреннему и наоборот.

Comment: Если у вас не осталось сомнений касательно данного вопроса, то выберите ответ который по вашему мнению наиболее полно раскрывает суть проблемы. И тогда вопрос можно будет считать закрытым )

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Шилдту следовало бы привести пример.
Вот что имеется ввиду:

```
class Outer {
    int outer_х = 100;

    class Inner {
        int inner_x = 200;

        void displayOuter () {
            System.out.println(outer_х); // вложенный класс имеет внешний. нормально
        }
    }

    void displayInner() {
        System.out.println(inner_х);  // ошибка. внешний класс не имеет доступа к членам вложенного класса 
    }

}
```

Доступ к членам вложенного класса возможен только через ссылку на экземпляр  вложенного класса.

```
Inner inner = new Inner(); 
println(inner.inner_x);
```

Comment: Справедливости ради, пример у Шилдта есть (в английской версии 9 редакции), по-сути такой же.

Comment: Действительно ниже по тексту у него есть подобный пример и детальное разъяснение насчёт доступа к членам. Очевидно дальше почти никто не читает:)

Answer (score 1):

Всё правильно написано. Внешний класс не имеет доступа к членам вложенного класса.
Попробуйте вызвать метод `displayVn()` или получить доступ к полю `vnutr_x` из `obj`, и всё прояснится

Comment: метод displayVn() я как раз и вызвал, но только во внешнем классе а именно в его методе test () и там же через vnutObj.vnutr_x++;  изменил поле внутреннего класса

Comment: Думаю, Шилдт имел ввиду, что внешний класс не имеет доступа к членам внутреннего класса при отсутствии экземпляра внутреннего класса (ну и экземпляра внешнего в дальнейшем)

Comment: @junior Так ведь к любому члену любого класса обращение идёт исключительно через экземпляр класса. Вложенный ничем в этом смысле не отличается от других классов. Но вложенный класс может обратиться к членам внешнего напрямую (потому что "знает своего хозяина")

Comment: @junior  Когда вы используете метод test вы лишь изменяете значение поля экземпляра vnutObj. При этом само поле в VnutrClass остаётся неизменным и доступа к нему вы не имеете. Это доказывает , то что если вы попробуете в методе test ()  получить доступ к полю vnutr_x например так 'VnutrClass.vnutr_x;' у вас это не выйдет. Так же вы можете проверить это вызвав два раза в main, метод test класса obj. При этом вы увидите, что значение не будет увеличиваться больше чем на 1. Потому, что при каждом вызове метода test, будет каждый раз  создаваться новый экземпляр класса VnutrClass

Comment: Спасибо! Нверное, я не правильно понимаю термин "доступ". Мне казалось, что если я изменяю значение поля экземпляра внутреннего класса, то я и получаю к нему доступ, как, например, если бы в методе внутреннего класса display_Vn()  я бы мог изменить поле "хозяина", следующей строкой outer_x++;

Comment: Неоднозначный термин. Если без паники продолжить читать книжку дальше, то буквально через несколько строк будет дано разъяснение тезиса про доступа в данном случае.